# SSRS Removes SQL Query Comments

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services, ssrs-2008

I've been trying to add comments to SQL in the query pane, but SSRS 2008R seems to remove them.

Have used

```
/*......*/
```

for block commenting, but they are removed after saving.

Does SSRS support SQL commenting?

Is there anyway to keep comments in?

Comment: Can you add a bit more information? I added a query like `/*comment*/ select * from sys.tables /*comment*/` in BIDS and it's saving the comments fine.

Comment: Just that when I edit the SQL query in the query designer - query pane - it loses the comments when I click OK. I can alter the SQL in all other ways, but can't save comments. I need to do this as SQL query is becoming a massive block of text and very time consuming to edit.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When editing SQL in BIDS, don't use the default Query Designer panes if you want to control the formatting of your text. Switch to "Edit as Text" mode and avoid ever switching out. Then comments and text formatting will be preserved.

The graphical UI in the default panes will liberally change the SQL statements. I really dislike that thing, and switch every dataset I touch to "Edit as Text."

Then I do heavy SQL editing in SSMS, with SQL Prompt installed, and paste into the BIDS dialog.

Comment: Yep. That does it. Cheers Jamie